# Javascript SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier when using php's echo to execute javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, i want to insert a div in the page when a specific condition arrives.
I'm checking the condition in PHP like:

```
if ($var == 0) {
    echo '<script>console.log("Test.");
    var res = document.getElementById("response");
    res.innerHTML = "<div class="hello">hi</div>";</script>';
}
```

So, what i think is that the single and double quotes are mixed within each other and its giving SyntaxError on this piece of code

```
echo '<script>res.innerHTML = "<div class="hello">hi</div>"</script>';
```

I tried writing

```
res.innerHTML = "<div class='hello'>hi</div>";
```

but then the code doesn't work as i'm using it inside php's echo for which I'm using single quotes('').

My basic goal here is to add a division with a class in my code if the condition satisfies. I'm checking the condition in PHP.
Can you please tell me how can i avoid getting that error, as the following works fine.

```
echo '<script>res.innerHTML = "<div>hi</div>"</script>';
```

Comment: Put it in one line:- `if ($var == 0) {
                echo '<script>console.log("Test.");var res = document.getElementById("response");res.innerHTML = "<div class="hello">hi</div>";</script>';
        }`

Comment: i would close the php tag and open it again

Comment: @AlivetoDie it is in one line, i just showed it in different lines, so that it can be seen clearly

Comment: The PHP part works perfectly: https://3v4l.org/7UTRY

Comment: @axiac `"<div class="hello">hi</div>"` is not valid Javascript.

Comment: @RolandStarke can you please show an example i'm still confused a bit.. Like this?
echo '<script>console.log("Test.");var res = document.getElementById("response");res.innerHTML = "<div class=';?><?php echo ' "hello">hi</div>";</script>';?>

Comment: @Keith yes, i used single quotes earlier but they affect the php code. Please guide me how to avoid it.

Comment: @Keith I updated my previous comment. The PHP part works fine. There are comments above that suggest different ways to fix the PHP but there is nothing to fix on that part.

Comment: @axiac The question is about Javascript SyntaxError. I know that the php part executes correctly. Please help me with javascript

Comment: @ashawe - stop with these comments and read the answer below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You need to escape the nested quotes in your html string:

```
res.innerHTML = "<div class=\\"hello\\">hi</div>";</script>'
```

You need double slash, because you also need to escape the slash in the PHP string.

Full example:

```
if ($var == 0) {
    echo '<script>console.log("Test."); var res = document.getElementById("response"); res.innerHTML = "<div class=\\"hello\\">hi</div>";</script>';
}
```

---

**Longer Answer**

A more detailed explanation of the problem...

If you echo your exact script, you will get the following javascript:

```
console.log("Test.");
var res = document.getElementById("response");
res.innerHTML = "<div class="hello">hi</div>";
```

As you will find, the 3rd line is invalid as you need to escape the inner quotes in the HTML. Normally you do this in JavaScript by using a combination of single and double quotes, however you are already using single quotes for the PHP. So you need to escape the quotes around `hello`.

Your aim should be to produce the following JavaScript:

```
console.log("Test.");
var res = document.getElementById("response");
res.innerHTML = "<div class=\"hello\">hi</div>";
```

Which can be done, with my suggestion at the start.

Of course, if you prefer you could escape single quotes instead:

```
res.innerHTML = \'<div class="hello">hi</div>\';</script>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would close the PHP mode, write the JavaScript and then enter the PHP mode again. It is more clear and less error-prone this way:

```
if ($var == 0) {
?>
    <script>
        console.log("Test.");
        var res = document.getElementById("response");
        res.innerHTML = '<div class="hello">hi</div>';
    </script>
<?php
}
```

If you need to use values stored in the PHP variables inside the generated JavaScript, this format makes everything a piece of cake (as opposed to building the script into a PHP string that requires a lot of escaping):

```
$message = 'hi';
if ($var == 0) {
?>
    <script>
        console.log("Test.");
        var res = document.getElementById("response");
        res.innerHTML = '<div class="hello"><?php echo(addslashes($message)); ?></div>';
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Need to use [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) to properly encode the value of `$message` because it is used to generate a [JavaScript string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings).

---

#### Update

As my discussion with @roland-starke in the comments revealed, a better alternative to `addcslashes()`is [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Take care that, given an PHP string, `json_encode()` generates a complete JavaScript string, including the double quotes that enclose it.

Using `json_encode()`, the code above becomes:

```
$message = 'hi';
if ($var == 0) {
?>
    <script>
        console.log("Test.");
        var res = document.getElementById("response");
        res.innerHTML = '<div class="hello">' +
                        <?php echo(json_encode($message)); ?> +
                        '</div>';
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I'd say this is a much cleaner approach than escaping server & client side.

Comment: `addslashes` is a bad idea, imagine a line break or `</script>` in message.

Comment: @RolandStarke really? Why would you put `</script>` in `$message`? To XSS your own code?

Comment: @axiac Although your approach of ending and starting the php tag is much better, escaping those quotes was what I needed for my code as there were some other things i needed to take care about.

Comment: @RolandStarke Because the content of `$message` is placed inside a JavaScript string, the characters that are special in JavaScript strings needs to be escaped. Imagine what happens if `$message = "O'Brian";`; the generated JavaScript code is invalid, it doesn't compile and it doesn't work. And no, using `addslashes()` in this context is not a bad idea. It is the reason why `addslashes()` exists.

Comment: @RolandStarke I don't need to imagine all these things. If you want to put `</script>` on screen then this is the way to do it. And this is what you want, otherwise you won't put `</script>` in `$message`.

Comment: Hmm... this is a semi well-known problem. The HTML parser finds `</script>` and thinks the script ends there. PHP and JavaScript are not guilty here.